# Setting value of a bound property from the setter of another bound property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, controls

I have a business object in C# which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and contains several bound properties.  In a nutshell, it looks like this:

```
public class BusinessObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private int _intProperty;
    public int IntProperty // bound to NumericUpDown control
    {
        get { return _intProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_intProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _intProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IntProperty"));

            // if IntProperty is > 10, then set BoolProperty to false
            if (value > 10)
            {
                this.BoolProperty = false;
                //OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BoolProperty"));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _boolProperty;
    public bool BoolProperty // bound to CheckBox
    {
        get { return _boolProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_boolProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _boolProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BoolProperty"));
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the setter for IntProperty, I'm setting the BoolProperty = false when IntProperty has been set > 10.  BoolProperty is bound to a CheckBox in my UI (winforms) but even though I'm setting BoolProperty = false, the CheckBox doesn't update to reflect that change until the control that's bound to IntProperty loses focus.  I thought maybe I needed to call OnPropertyChanged after I set BoolProperty = false but that didn't seem to make a difference.  Is this the expected behavior in this scenario?  If so, is it possible to implement the behavior that I've described?

Comment: What's the DataSourceUpdateMode on your binding, it should be DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I had created all of my bindings using the designer and I set them by clicking on the appropriate property.  So I assume that DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation is the default if you don't use the "Advanced" DataBindings dialog in the designer or set your bindings in code and specify it?  Anyway, thank you very much for the quick reply.  If you'd like to "answer" my question with this info, I'll gladly accept and upvote it for you.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set the binding's `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`